# Chromium changed font and no clue to change it back

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-drive-api

How can I change font to change it back because this font is not easy to read.

[image]

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1
- Chromium Version 87.0.4280.141

Comment: how did you even get there?!

Comment: No clue, I suspend my computer and the next time I log in that was the font I bumped into

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related. OP should check how to change font in their browser

Comment: @DalmTo I'm sorry to bother you with this question but I was not a problem of changing the font but a google chrome bug that I had to reset the browser and even reboot to get the default settings I already had. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2331445?hl=en